# The calculation logic of stats func pmf and cdf

Tags: python, scipy.stats

Below is some codes in scipy.stats module, I'm confused where the "_cdf" func calls the "_pmf" func and "_pmf" also calls "_cdf", how to end the circle?

```
self._cdfvec = vectorize(self._cdf_single, otypes='d')
...

def _pmf(self, k, *args):
    return self._cdf(k, *args) - self._cdf(k-1, *args)
...

def _cdf_single(self, k, *args):
    m = arange(int(self.a), k+1)
    return np.sum(self._pmf(m, *args), axis=0)

def _cdf(self, x, *args):
    k = floor(x)
    return self._cdfvec(k, *args)
```

Answer (score 1):

These are the generic implementations in the `rv_discrete` infrastructure, but  when creating a specific distribution, a developer subclasses `rv_discrete`. SciPy developers override `_pmf` (and often `_cdf`) in these subclasses, avoiding the infinite recursion.  In principle, however, this structure allows the developer to override *either* `_pmf`*or* `_cdf`, and the one left undefined in the subclass would be computed from the one that has been overridden.